# $\mathbb{R}^3$ as a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, euclidean-geometry, noncommutative-algebra, quaternions

I have read in an introduction to quaternions that it had been proven before that one can not structure the Euclidian $\mathbb{R}^3$ as a field.

Where can one find a proof thereof?

For which n, could we bestow $\mathbb{R}^n$ with a field structure?

Comment: The inventor of the quaternions tried for a long time to do it before going on to $\mathbb R^4$, maybe he found a proof why it was impossible. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Rowan_Hamilton

Comment: What would count as a good field structure on $\mathbb{R}^n$? I mean, in theory one could fix a bijection $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ and define operations on $\mathbb{R}^n$ by 'pulling back' the normal field operations from $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @mathreadler no according to my textbook a proof was found long after he passed.

Comment: It is provable that a [division algebra](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_algebra) over the real numbers must have dimension a power of two.

Comment: See also:  Hurwitz's theorem.

Answer (score 6):

Just as a set, $\mathbb{R}^n$ has the same cardinality as $\mathbb{R}$. We can therefore fix a bijection $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ and define the field operations and constants on $\mathbb{R}^n$ by pulling back the known operations from $\mathbb{R}$ (e.g. for $x, y \in \mathbb{R}^n$, define $x + y = f^{-1}(f(x) + f(y))$). This makes $\mathbb{R}^n$ into a field, for any $n$.

Since you mentioned quaternions, I assume your question might have been: "For which $n$ can we make $\mathbb{R}^n$ into a field *which respects the natural structure as an $n$-dimensional $\mathbb{R}$-vector space*?" The answer is given by the Frobenius theorem: $n=1, 2$ if we need the field to be commutative, $n=4$ is also possible if we allow non-commutative fields.

Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_theorem_(real_division_algebras)

Comment: If you're only interested in the commutative case, the complicated arguments of the Frobenius theorem are unneeded, since it follows immediately from the fact that $\mathbb{C}$ is algebraically closed that no other finite field extensions of $\mathbb{R}$ can exist.

Answer (score 3):

The only $n$ for which $\mathbb R^n$ is a field are $n=1,2,4$ the case of quaternions being the first example known of non-commutative field. A proof of the impossibility for $n=3$ you can read in "Algèbre linéaire et géométrie élémentaire" of Jean Dieudonné, p. 197, Hermann,Paris, 1964. There is english translation of this book.

Comment: Thank you for the reference

Comment: You are welcome.